# Pointer to a specific fixed address

Tags: c, pointers

How do you assign a specific memory address to a pointer?

The Special Function Registers in a microcontroller such AVR m128 has fixed addresses, the AVR GCC defines the SFR in the io.h header file, but I want to handle it myself.

Answer (score 39):

Sure, no problem.  You can just assign it directly to a variable:

```
volatile unsigned int *myPointer = (volatile unsigned int *)0x12345678;
```

What I usually do is declare a memory-mapped I/O macro:

```
#define mmio32(x)   (*(volatile unsigned long *)(x))
```

And then define my registers in a header file:

```
#define SFR_BASE    (0xCF800000)
#define SFR_1       (SFR_BASE + 0x0004)
#define SFR_2       (SFR_BASE + 0x0010)
```

And then use them:

```
unsigned long registerValue = mmio32(SFR_1); // read
mmio32(SFR2) = 0x85748312;                   // write
```

Comment: I would have used a generic void pointer, unless the data at that location is an unsigned int.

Comment: It's usually  a good idea to declare memory-mapped I/O addresses as `volatile`.

Comment: @Sean, he wants to access a memory mapped register.  You can't dereference a `void` pointer, what use would that be?

Comment: Well, you could make it volatile void * so that they can't access it casually except by using mmio32(). I wouldn't do it that way, perhaps that's what you want?