# Why is address zero used for the null pointer?

Tags: c++, c, memory, pointers

In C (or C++ for that matter), pointers are special if they have the value zero: I am adviced to set pointers to zero after freeing their memory, because it means freeing the pointer again isn't dangerous; when I call malloc it returns a pointer with the value zero if it can't get me memory; I use `if (p != 0)` all the time to make sure passed pointers are valid, etc.

But since memory addressing starts at 0, isn't 0 just as a valid address as any other? How can 0 be used for handling null pointers if that is the case? Why isn't a negative number null instead?

---

Edit:

A bunch of good answers. I'll summarize what has been said in the answers expressed as my own mind interprets it and hope that the community will correct me if I misunderstand.

- Like everything else in programming it's an abstraction. Just a constant, not really related to the address 0. C++0x emphasizes this by adding the keyword `nullptr`.
- It's not even an address abstraction, it's the constant specified by the C standard and the compiler can translate it to some other number as long as it makes sure it never equals a "real" address, and equals other null pointers if 0 is not the best value to use for the platform.
- In case it's not an abstraction, which was the case in the early days, the address 0 is used by the system and off limits to the programmer.
- My negative number suggestion was a little wild brainstorming, I admit. Using a signed integer for addresses is a little wasteful if it means that apart from the null pointer (-1 or whatever) the value space is split evenly between positive integers that make valid addresses and negative numbers that are just wasted.
- If any number is always representable by a datatype, it's 0. (Probably 1 is too. I think of the one-bit integer which would be 0 or 1 if unsigned, or just the signed bit if signed, or the two bit integer which would be [-2, 1]. But then you could just go for 0 being null and 1 being the only accessible byte in memory.)

Still there is something that is unresolved in my mind. The Stack Overflow question *[Pointer to a specific fixed address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389251)* tells me that even if 0 for null pointer is an abstraction, other pointer values aren't necessarily. This leads me to post another Stack Overflow question, *[Could I ever want to access the address zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761360)*.

Comment: You could just as easily change `if (p != 0)` to `if (p)` which is a common idiom in C and C++, although you'll have to get out of the habit if you take up Java.

Comment: Deleting something twice means your code is wrong. I advise against setting pointers to null after so you can crash and fix the problem, not suppress it. In any case, you make the mistake of assuming an address is some integer. This isn't necessarily true, and 0 merely *represents* some actual pointer value which is implementation-specific. A "negative address" doesn't make sense, conceptually.

Comment: @GMan: Maybe even a good idea to set the pointer to an address which will force a crash, such as `0xDEADBEEF`.

Comment: The question that will never die!

Comment: Don't follow GMan's advice.  Multiple deletion *may* indicate a theoretical issue but is never going to cause a problem.  Dereferencing/deleting an invalid pointer on the other hand is always an issue BUT! does not necessarily result in a crash.  There are many, many cases in which you can dereference an invalid pointer and it simply results in complete insanity and maybe a crash *later*.  The only time you can actually bet (and not by standard) that you'll get a crash is if you access outside your program space, which null will definitely be.  UB can cause hours of extra debug time.

Comment: @Noah: The point is set to null -> hide programming errors, don't set to null -> find programming errors. I don't know about you, but I'd like to have my code correct.

Comment: Addresses are unsigned,a negative value could just represent a really high value in memory, depending on how the OS maps virtual memory.

Comment: @Robert: Since this question is in language-land, I'll point out addresses are not necessarily unsigned integers.

Comment: Since non-char* pointers are virtually always aligned (often on an 8-byte boundary these days) it can be beneficial to fill deallocated memory with rubbish bytes with the LSB set. I use 0x61 but that's arbitrary. (The benefit? It gives you an error/signal due to non-aligned access when you dereference it.)

Comment: @gman - you're not going to make your code correct by invoking nasal demons.  Deleting pointers twice is never incorrect code.  It may or may not be a design issue but it is *never* an error.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: According to the C standard, free()ing a pointer twice results in undefined behavior.  I don't know about you, but I try to avoid that in my programs.

Comment: @Daniel - yes, of course I neglected to reassert that this is only the case when the pointer has been set to 0 since freeing a 0 ptr is a nop.  I didn't consider it necessary since the position I'm arguing against is that not setting a pointer to null somehow makes it easier to find code errors caused by deleting a pointer twice.

Comment: @Noah: Do you disagree that deleting a pointer twice is sometimes a logic error?

Comment: My mentioning of the advice to set pointer to null after deletion caused quite a discussion. I don't really have a stand myself, and I certainly don't rely on either practice. For the interested, this discussion has its page here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931126/is-it-good-practice-to-null-a-pointer-after-deleting-it

Comment: gman is correct. The whole point in C is to avoid the overhead of checking constraints at runtime, otherwise you'd be coding in a sane language such as Java. There are only a few rare cases where you will double free something, especially since it has to be NULL first..

Comment: @Longpoke - are you sure you mean to agree with gman->don't set a pointer to null after deleting it because you want to crash if you accidentally free it again...  Your wording sounds otherwise.

Comment: @dennis - define "logic error".  It can sometimes be that a null pointer getting deleted is because something else is going on that shouldn't be.  If that exposes itself as a bug in the program then it is an error.  If the only thing that goes "wrong" is that a null pointer is passed to free() or delete then I think you need to rethink your definition of "error".  Furthermore, the alternative that gman is proposing does not guarantee anything.  Deleting a pointer that is invalid is UB, not "crash".  More often than not it will exhibit itself in totally insane ways.

Comment: @Noah Roberts, I'm agreeing with gman that you shouldn't set the pointer to _anything_ to mark it invalid, unless that's your "alive" flag... Ie: If you have a struct with 3 pointers, and a flag saying weather the struct is alive, you only set that flag and leave the pointers as-is after freeing them.

Comment: @Noah: If you pass a pointer to a function that believes the pointer is still live, and it is not, then that is a logic error.  Even when they don't directly cause crashes, avoiding them is not without merit.  It tends to make modifications easier if the code functions as expected rather than as promised.  I'm not arguing that you shouldn't set dead pointers to null, but saying double deletion is never an error is simply wrong.

Comment: _"memory addressing starts at 0"_ [citation needed]

Comment: One more nitpicky detail  A one bit signed integer has two distinct values: 0 and -1, represented as 0 and 1 as the single bit's value, respectively :)

Comment: Setting a pointer to null after freeing it may hide double-free design errors. _Not_ setting it to null may hide used-after-freed errors. The latter is orders of magnitude more severe. If a pointer is no longer valid, you _want_ any attempt at dereferencing it to result in well-defined behavior instead of unpredictable memory corruption. Those bugs are hell to track down and can be a security hole.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

2 points:

- only the constant value 0 in the source code is the null pointer - the compiler implementation can use whatever value it wants or needs in the running code.  Some platforms have a special pointer value that's 'invalid' that the implementation might use as the null pointer. The C FAQ has a question, ["Seriously, have any actual machines really used nonzero null pointers, or different representations for pointers to different types?"](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html), that points out several platforms that used this property of 0 being the null pointer in C source while represented differently at runtime. The C++ standard has a note that makes clear that converting "an integral constant expression with value zero always yields a null pointer, but converting other expressions that happen to have value zero need not yield a null pointer".
- a negative value might be just as usable by the platform as an address - the C standard simply had to chose something to use to indicate a null pointer, and zero was chosen.  I'm honestly not sure if other sentinel values were considered.

The only requirements for a null pointer are:

- it's guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to an actual object
- any two null pointers will compare equal (C++ refines this such that this only needs to hold for pointers to the same type)

Comment: +1 I suspect 0 was chosen merely for historical reasons. (0 being a starting and invalid address, most of the time.) Of course in general such an assumption isn't always true, but 0 works pretty well.

Comment: Space may also have been a contributing factor.  In the days when C was first developed, memory was MUCH more costly than now.  The number zero can be conveniently calculated using an XOR instruction or without the need to load an immediate value.  Depending upon the architecture, this could potentially save space.

Comment: @GMan - You are correct.  On early CPUs, memory address zero was special and had hardware protection against access from running software (in some cases it was the start of the reset vector, and modifying it could prevent the CPU from resetting or starting up).  Programmers used this hardware protection as a form of error detection in their software, letting the CPU's address decode logic check for uninitialized or invalid pointers instead of having to spend CPU instructions to do it.  The convention remains to this day, even though the purpose of address zero may have changed.

Comment: Minix 16 bit compiler used 0xFFFF for NULL.

Comment: In many embedded systems, 0 is a valid address.  The value -1 (all bits one) is also a valid address.  Checksums for ROMs are hard to calculate when the data starts at address 0. :-(

Comment: Accepted on the combined merits of having the core of the most answers and vote count.

Comment: In some machines testing for 0 is quicker than testing for other values. (Testing for the zero flag after an operation) This could have been a contributing factor also.

Comment: 0 makes a nice null pointer constant because it's also a zero for the other arithmetic types.  If x is a scalar type, then x = 0 sets it to null pointer, 0.0 or integer 0, based on its type. Also, the initializer {0} can initialize anything: pointer, struct, number, array, ... this is because even if the object being initialized is scalar, there can be optional braces around the initializer.

Comment: Do modern CPUs / MMU protect against accessing 0x0 as well? That is, is a Ring 0 kernel allowed to access 0x0?

Comment: So there is no guarantee that in `if (p) ...`, the condition evaluates to false if and only if `p` is a *null pointer*? Do I really compare it with `nullptr` (or `NULL`)?

Comment: @leemes: `if (p)` is fine because the standard say that the "first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0".  There's similar language for the controlling expression in loops. The C++ standard frames it in terms of a `bool` expression and a "null pointer value" converts to `false`, otherwise `true`. The null pointer value is what the null pointer constant converts to when used as a pointer type.

Comment: "used this property of 0 being the null pointer in C source" is amiss.  `0` is not a _pointer_ nor a _null pointer_.  It is an integer constant with type `int`.  With `#define NULL 0`, `NULL` is the _null pointer constant_, yet it is not a pointer in the case, but an `int`.  With `#define NULL ((void*)0)`, `NULL` is also a the _null pointer constant_, and a pointer in the case.  In C, `NULL`, converted to a pointer type, is  a _null pointer_.

Comment: @Sparky: Yes, some ISAs can create a `0` more easily than a `-1`, and a small non-zero integer constant (that could fit in an immediate operand on most machines) wouldn't make any sense.  Also, *testing* for zero has special support in most ISAs.  e.g. to parse an integer literal, you probably added the last digit to the total with an instruction that set CPU condition-codes, aka flags, on CPUs that use a status register at all.  (Most other than MIPS).  There's always a zero flag that's set if the last result was zero, so you don't need a separate compare instruction, just `jz` or `jnz`.

Answer (score 34):

Historically, the address space starting at 0 was always ROM, used for some operating system or low level interrupt handling routines, nowadays, since everything is virtual (including address space), the operating system can map any allocation to any address, so it can specifically NOT allocate anything at address 0.

Comment: That pretty much is it. It is by historical convention, and the first addreses were used for interrupt handlers, thus are unusable for normal programs. Also, 0 is "empty", which can be interpreted as no value / no pointer.

Comment: Its not true that address 0 is always a non valid address, but I guess that's why the standard allows the use of any constant. I am still not sure how it is guaranteed that the NULL is not a valid address unless the number of bits used to store a pointer value is greater than the number of bits on REM address bus.

Comment: On Linux for example, you can set `/proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr` to `0`, making it possible to `mmap` that virtual address.  Some packages actually do that, like older QEMU, and WINE for 16-bit-Windows programs, according to https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr .  But yes, most systems with virtual memory set things up so NULL-deref faults using `0` as the bit-pattern for null pointers.  (And some area around that, in case code was attempting to index an array.)

Answer (score 16):

IIRC, the "null pointer" value isn't guaranteed to be zero.  The compiler translates 0 into whatever "null" value is appropriate for the system (which in practice is probably always zero, but not necessarily).  The same translation is applied whenever you compare a pointer against zero.  Because you can only compare pointers against each other and against this special-value-0, it insulates the programmer from knowing anything about the memory representation of the system.  As for why they chose 0 instead of 42 or somesuch, I'm going to guess it's because most programmers start counting at 0 :)  (Also, on most systems 0 is the first memory address and they wanted it to be convenient, since in practice translations like I'm describing rarely actually take place; the language just allows for them).

Comment: @Justin: You misunderstood. The constant 0 is *always* the null pointer. What @meador is saying is that it's possible that the null pointer (indicated by the constant 0) does not correspond to the address zero. On some platforms, creating a null pointer (`int* p = 0`) might create a pointer containing the value `0xdeadbeef` or any other value it prefers. 0 is a null pointer, but a null pointer is not necessarily a pointer to address zero. :)

Comment: A NULL pointer is a reserved value and depending on the compiler could be any bit pattern. NULL pointer does not mean that it points to address 0.

Comment: But @Jalf, the constant 0 *isn't* always the null pointer. It's what we write when we want the compiler to fill in the platform's *actual* null pointer for us. Practically speaking, the null pointer usually *does* correspond to the address zero, though, and I interpret Joel's question as asking why that is. There's supposedly a valid byte of memory at that address, after all, so why not use a non-existent address of a non-existent byte instead of removing a valid byte from play? (I'm writing what I imagine Joel was thinking, not a question I'm asking myself.)

Comment: @Rob: Sort of. I know what you mean, and you're correct, but so am I. :)
The constant integer 0 represents the null pointer at a source code level. Comparing a null pointer to 0 yields true. Assigning 0 to a pointer sets that pointer to null. 0 *is* the null pointer.
But the actual in-memory representation of a null pointer might be different from the zero bit pattern. (Anyway, my comment was in response to @Justin's now deleted comment, not to @Joel's question. :)

Comment: @jalf @Rob You need some terms to clarify, I think. :) From §4.10/1: "A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of pointer to object or pointer to function type."

Comment: @jalf In C, `0` is not a _null pointer_ - it is an `int`.  Example: `printf("%p\n", 0);` is UB.  `0`, when converted to a pointer type,  is a _null pointer_.

Answer (score 16):

You must be misunderstanding the meaning of constant zero in pointer context.

Neither in C nor in C++ pointers can "have value zero". Pointers are not arithmetic objects. They canot have numerical values like "zero" or "negative" or anything of that nature. So your statement about "pointers ... have the value zero" simply makes no sense.

In C & C++ pointers can have the reserved *null-pointer value*. The actual representation of null-pointer value has nothing to do with any "zeros". It can be absolutely anything appropriate for a given platform. It is true that on most plaforms null-pointer value is represented physically by an actual zero address value. However, if on some platform address 0 is actually used for some purpose (i.e. you might need to create objects at address 0), the null-pointer value on such platform will most likely be different. It could be physically represented as `0xFFFFFFFF` address value or as `0xBAADBAAD` address value, for example.

Nevertheless, regardless of how the null-pointer value is respresented on a given platform, in your code you will still continue to designate null-pointers by constant `0`. In order to assign a null-pointer value to a given pointer, you will continue to use expressions like `p = 0`. It is the compiler's responsibility to realize what you want and translate it into the proper null-pointer value representation, i.e. to translate it into the code that will put the address value of `0xFFFFFFFF` into the pointer `p`, for example.

In short, the fact that you use `0` in your sorce code to generate null-pointer values does not mean that the null-pointer value is somehow tied to address `0`. The `0` that you use in your source code is just "syntactic sugar" that has absolutely no relation to the actual physical address the null-pointer value is "pointing" to.

Comment: <quote>Pointers are not arithmetic objects</quote>  Pointer arithmetic is quite well defined in C and C++.  Part of the requirement is that both pointers point within the same composite.  The null pointer doesn't point to any composite so using it in pointer arithmetic expressions is illegal.  For example, it is not guaranteed that `(p1 - nullptr) - (p2 - nullptr) == (p1 - p2)`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: The language specification defines the notion of *arithmetic type*. All I'm saying is that pointer types do not belong to the category of arithmetic types. *Pointer arithmetic* is a different and completely unrelated story, a mere linguistic coincidence.

Comment: How is someone reading *arithmetic objects* supposed to know it means "in the sense of arithmetic types" and not "in the sense of arithmetic operators" (several of which are usable on pointers) or "in the sense of pointer arithmetic". As far as linguistic coincidences are concerned, *arithmetic object* has more letters in common with *pointer arithmetic* than *arithmetic types*. At the same time, the standard does talk about *pointer value*. The original poster probably meant *integer representation of a pointer* rather than *pointer value*, and `NULL` explicitly need not be represented by 0.

Comment: Well, for example the term *scalar objects* in C/C++ terminology is just a shorthand for *objects of scalar types* (just like *POD objects* = *objects of POD types*). I used the term *arithmetic objects* in exactly the same way, meaning *objects of arithmetic types*. I expect "someone" to understand it that way. Someone who doesn't can always ask for a clarification.

Comment: i worked on a system where (as far as the hardware was concerned) null was 0xffffffff and 0 was a perfectly valid address

Answer (score 8):

> But since memory addressing starts at 0, isn't 0 just as a valid address as any other?

On some/many/all operating systems, memory address 0 is special in some way. For example, it's often mapped to invalid/non-existent memory, which causes an exception if you try to access it.

> Why isn't a negative number null instead?

I think that pointer values are typically treated as unsigned numbers: otherwise for example a 32-bit pointer would only be able to address 2 GB of memory, instead of 4 GB.

Comment: I've coded on a device where address zero was a valid address, and there was no memory protection. Null pointers were also all-bits-zero; if you accidentally wrote to a null pointer then you blasted over the OS settings that were at the zero address; hilarity usually didn't ensue.

Comment: Yes: on a non-protected-mode x86 CPU, for example, address 0 is the [interrupt vector table](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)).

Comment: @ChrisW: On non-protected-mode x86, address zero in particular is the divide-by-zero interrupt vector, which some programs might have entirely legitimate reasons for writing.

Comment: Even on platforms where usable storage would start at physical address, zero, a C implementation could easily either use address zero to hold an object whose address is never taken, or else simply leave the first word of memory unused.  On most platforms, compare-with-zero saves an instruction versus compare-with-anything-else, so even wasting the first word of storage would be cheaper than using a non-zero address for null.  Note that there's no requirement that the addresses of things not covered by the C Standard (e.g. I/O ports or interrupt vectors) compare unequal to null, nor that...

Comment: ...the system process null-pointer accesses any differently from any other, so all-bits-zero is generally a fine address for "null" even on systems where accesses to physical location zero would be useful and meaningful.

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be that the magic value 0 was picked to define an invalid pointer since it could be tested for with less instructions. Some machine languages automatically set the zero and sign flags according to the data when loading registers so you could test for a null pointer with a simple load then and branch instructions without doing a separate compare instruction.

(Most ISAs only set flags on ALU instructions, not loads, though.  And usually you aren't producing pointers via computation, except in the compiler when parsing C *source*.  But at least you don't need an arbitrary pointer-width constant to compare against.)

On the Commodore Pet, Vic20, and C64 which were the first machines I worked on, RAM started at location 0 so it was totally valid to read and write using a null pointer if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's just a convention. There must be some value to mark an invalid pointer.

You just lose one byte of address space, that should rarely be a problem.

There are no negative pointers. Pointers are always unsigned. Also if they could be negative your convention would mean that you lose half the address space.

Comment: Note: you don't actually lose address space; you can get a pointer to address 0 by doing: `char *p = (char *)1; --p;` . Since behaviour on a null pointer is undefined by the standard, this system can have `p` actually read and write address 0, increment to give address `1`, etc.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: An implementation where address zero is a valid hardware address may perfectly legitimately *define* the behavior of `char x = ((char*)0);` to read address zero and store that value into x.  Such code would yield Undefined Behavior on any implementation which didn't define its behavior, but the fact that a standard says something is Undefined Behavior in no way forbids implementations from offering their own specifications for what it will do.

Comment: @supercat ITYM `*(char *)0`. That's true, but in my suggestion the implementation does not need to define the behaviour of `*(char *)0` or of any other null pointer operations.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: The behavior of `char *p = (char*)1; --p;` would only be defined by the standard if that sequence had been performed after a pointer to something other than the first byte of an object had been cast to an `intptr_t`, and the result of that cast happened to yield the value 1, and in that particular case the result of `--p` would yield a pointer to the byte preceding the one whose pointer value, when cast to `intptr_t`, had yielded `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Although C uses 0 to represent the null pointer, do keep in mind that the value of the pointer itself may not be a zero.  However, most programmers will only ever use systems where the null pointer is, in fact, 0.

But why zero?  Well, it's one address that every system shares.  And oftentimes the low addresses are reserved for operating system purposes thus the value works well as being off-limits to application programs.  Accidental assignment of an integer value to a pointer is as likely to end up zero as anything else.

Comment: The more likely reason behind all this is that: it is cheap to hand out memory that is pre-initialized to zero and convenient to have values in that memory represent something meaningful like integer 0, floating point 0.0 and null pointers.  Static data in C that is initialized to zero/null does not have to occupy any space in the executable and is mapped to a zero-filled block when loaded. Zero may get special treatment in machine languages also: easy zero comparisons like "branch if equal to zero", etc. MIPS even has a dummy register that is just a zero constant.

Answer (score 2):

Historically the low memory of an application was occupied by system resources.  It was in those days that zero became the default null value.

While this is not necessarily true for modern systems, it is still a bad idea to set pointer values to anything but what memory allocation has handed you.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the argument about not setting a pointer to null after deleting it so that future deletes "expose errors"...

If you're really, really worried about this then a better approach, one that is guaranteed to work, is to leverage assert():

```
...
assert(ptr && "You're deleting this pointer twice, look for a bug?");
delete ptr;
ptr = 0;
...
```

This requires some extra typing, and one extra check during debug builds, but it is certain to give you what you want: notice when ptr is deleted 'twice'.  The alternative given in the comment discussion, not setting the pointer to null so you'll get a crash, is simply not guaranteed to be successful.  Worse, unlike the above, it can cause a crash (or much worse!) on a user if one of these "bugs" gets through to the shelf.  Finally, this version lets you continue to run the program to see what actually happens.

I realize this does not answer the question asked, but I was worried that someone reading the comments might come to the conclusion that it is considered 'good practice' to NOT set pointers to 0 if it is possible they get sent to free() or delete twice.  In those few cases when it is possible it is NEVER a good practice to use Undefined Behavior as a debugging tool.  Nobody that's ever had to hunt down a bug that was ultimately caused by deleting an invalid pointer would propose this.  These kinds of errors take hours to hunt down and nearly alway effect the program in a totally unexpected way that is hard to impossible to track back to the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

An important reason why many operating systems use all-bits-zero for the null pointer representation, is that this means `memset(struct_with_pointers, 0, sizeof struct_with_pointers)` and similar will set all of the pointers inside `struct_with_pointers` to null pointers.  This is not guaranteed by the C standard, but many, many programs assume it.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the old DEC machines (PDP-8, I think), the C runtime would memory protect the first page of memory so that any attempt to access memory in that block would cause an exception to be raised.

Comment: The PDP-8 had no C compiler.  The PDP-11 had no memory protection and the VAX was infamous for silently returning 0 to NULL pointer dereferences.  I am not sure which machine this refers to.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of sentinel value is arbitrary, and this is in fact being addressed by the next version of C++ (informally known as "C++0x", most likely to be known in the future as ISO C++ 2011) with the introduction of the keyword `nullptr` to represent a null valued pointer. In C++, a value of 0 may be used as an initializing expression for any POD and for any object with a default constructor, and it has the special meaning of assigning the sentinel value in the case of a pointer initialization. As for why a negative value was not chosen, addresses usually range from 0 to 2<sup>N</sup>-1 for some value N. In other words, addresses are usually treated as unsigned values. If the maximum value were used as the sentinel value, then it would have to vary from system to system depending on the size of memory whereas 0 is always a representable address. It is also used for historical reasons, as memory address 0 was typically unusable in programs, and nowadays most OSs have parts of the kernel loaded into the lower page(s) of memory, and such pages are typically protected in such a way that if touched  (dereferenced) by a program (save the kernel) will cause a fault.

Answer (score 1):

It has to have some value. Obviously you don't want to step on values the user might legitimately want to use. I would speculate that since the C runtime provides the BSS segment for zero-initialized data, it makes a certain degree of sense to interpret zero as an un-initialized pointer value.

Answer (score 0):

Rarely does an OS allow you to write to address 0.  It's common to stick OS-specific stuff down in low memory; namely, IDTs, page tables, etc.  (The tables have to be in RAM, and it's easier to stick them at the bottom than to try and determine where the top of RAM is.)  And no OS in its right mind will let you edit system tables willy-nilly.

This may not have been on K&R's minds when they made C, but it (along with the fact that 0==null is pretty easy to remember) makes 0 a popular choice.

Comment: This isn't true in protected mode, and in fact, on certain Linux configurations, you _can_ write to virtual address 0.

Answer (score 0):

The value `0` is a special value that takes on various meanings in specific expressions. In the case of pointers, as has been pointed out many many times, it is used probably because at the time it was the most convenient way of saying "insert the default sentinel value here." As a constant expression, it does not have the same meaning as bitwise zero (i.e., all bits set to zero) in the context of a pointer expression. In C++, there are several types that do not have a bitwise zero representation of `NULL` such as pointer member and pointer to member function.

Thankfully, C++0x has a new keyword for "expression that means a known invalid pointer that does not also map to bitwise zero for integral expressions": `nullptr`. Although there are a few systems that you can target with C++ that allow dereferencing of address 0 without barfing, so programmer beware.

Answer (score 0):

There are already a lot of good answers in this thread; there are probably many different reasons for preferring the value `0` for null pointers, but I'm going to add two more:

- In C++, zero-initializing a pointer will set it to null.
- On many processors it is more efficient to set a value to 0 or to test for it equal/not equal to 0 than for any other constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on the implementation of pointers in C/C++. There is no specific reason why NULL is equivalent in assignments to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer is not the same thing with null value. For example the same strchr function of c will return a null pointer (empty on the console), while passing the value would return (null) on the console.

True function:

```
char *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    int i;

    if (!s)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (s[i])
    {
        if (s[i] == (char)c)
            return ((char*)(s + i));
        i++;
    }
    **if (s[i] == (char)c)
        return ((char*)(s + i));**
    return (NULL);
}
```

This will produce  empty thing as the output: [the last || is the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xYQC.png)

While passing as value like s[i] gives us a NULL like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JQtf.png)

```
char *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    int i;

    if (!s)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (s[i])
    {
        if (s[i] == (char)c)
            return ((char*)(s + i));
        i++;
    }
    **if (s[i] == (char)c)
        return (s[i]);**
    return (NULL);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are historic reasons for this, but there are also optimization reasons for it.

It is common for the OS to provide a process with memory pages initialized to 0.  If a program wants to interpret part of that memory page as a pointer then it is 0, so it is easy enough for the program to determine that that pointer is not initialized.  (this doesn't work so well when applied to uninitialized flash pages)

Another reason is that on many many processors it is very very easy to test a value's equivalence to 0.  It is sometimes a free comparison done without any extra instructions needed, and usually can be done without needing to provide a zero value in another register or as a literal in the instruction stream to compare to.

The cheap comparisons for most processors are the signed less than 0, and equal to 0.  (signed greater than 0 and not equal to 0 are implied by both of these)

Since 1 value out of all of possible values needs to be reserved as bad or uninitialized then you might as well make it the one that has the cheapest test for equivalence to the bad value.  This is also true for '\0' terminated character strings.

If you were to try to use greater or less than 0 for this purpose then you would end up chopping your range of addresses in half.

Answer (score -2):

The constant `0` is used instead of `NULL` because C was made by some cavemen trillions of years ago, `NULL`, `NIL`, `ZIP`, or `NADDA` would have all made much more sense than `0`.

> But since memory addressing starts at
>   0, isn't 0 just as a valid address as
>   any other?

Indeed. Although a lot of operating systems disallow you from mapping anything at address zero, even in a virtual address space (people realized C is an insecure language, and reflecting that null pointer dereference bugs are very common, decided to "fix" them by dissallowing the userspace code to map to page 0; Thus, if you call a callback but the callback pointer is NULL, you wont end up executing some arbitrary code).

> How can 0 be used for handling null
>   pointers if that is the case?

Because `0` used in comparison to a pointer will be replaced with some *implementation specific* value, which is the return value of malloc on a malloc failure.

> Why isn't a negative number null
>   instead?

This would be even more confusing.

Comment: Your point about "cavemen", etc. probably lies at the root of it, though I think the specifics are different.  The earliest forms of what evolved into C were designed to run on one particular architecture where an `int` was not only the same size as a pointer--in many contexts an `int` and a pointer could be used interchangeably.  If a routine expected a pointer and one passed in an integer 57, the routine would use address with the same bit pattern as the number 57.  On those particular machines, the bit pattern to denote a null pointer was 0, so passing an int 0 would pass a null pointer.

Comment: Since that time, the C has evolved so that it can be used to write programs for a huge variety of other machines with different representations of numbers and pointers.  While non-zero numeric constants were seldom used as pointers, constant numeric zeroes were widely used to represent null pointers.  To disallow such usage would have broken existing code, so compilers have been expected to translate a numeric zero into whatever the implementation uses to represent a null pointer.