# Assigning pointer to bitwise OR of two pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I'm implementing `remove` method for binary search tree in C++. In one of cases I am sure that tree `node` has only one child: `node->left` or `node->right` and I need to modify it's parent to point to that child. As I mentioned before one of `node->left` and `node->right` are `NULL`. Here's a snippet:

```c
} else { // One children
  if (node->parent->left == node) {
    node->parent->left = node->left | node->right;
    node->parent->left->parent = node->parent;
  } else {
    node->parent->right = node->left | node->right;
    node->parent->right->parent = node->parent;
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, compiler returns an error. I know that it's maybe not the elegant one but I was just curious how to do it.

Comment: "An error"? What error.

Comment: Why would you **ever** want to do this?

Comment: what did you think is the effect of `pointer | pointer`?

Comment: @Walter Pointers are numbers. So if I OR two numbers from which one is zero (NULL) I should get the second number.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious so I can write it in 1 line rather than 5.

Comment: @keepkimi First of all, pointers are not numbers. They are pointers. Second, `NULL` is not necessarily the number 0.

Comment: [null pointers aren't necessarily 0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2759845/1281433)

Comment: Wow, harsh crowd. I don't see any reason why this needed to be put on hold.

Comment: To be more specific: it's well known that pointers contain addresses, and addresses consist of a bit pattern. Asking why bit manipulation of an address doesn't work is perfectly valid. Someone coming from an assembler background would especially be confused, although I suspect that's rare these days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bit manipulation on pointers isn't supported by C++ or C. You can convert them to integers, do the `or`, then convert back, but that's just asking for trouble for no particular gain.

Use ternary expressions instead:

```
node->parent->left = node->left ? node->left : node->right;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that would achieve what you want.  Assigning your pointers the result of a bitwise OR of two other pointers would result in a pointer that points to who knows where.

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
} else { // One children
  if (node->parent->left == node) {
    node->parent->left = node->left != null ? node->left : node->right;
    node->parent->left->parent = node->parent;
  } else {
    node->parent->right = node->left | node->right;
    node->parent->right->parent = node->parent;
  }
}
```