# NSString equals 0?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I stumbled across the following code when coding. I'm wondering how it even compiles without warning?

`NSString *str = 0`

Logging it returns `(null)` so it's not setting the string literally. Why does this work?

Comment: Have a look at [nil / Nil / NULL / NSNull](http://nshipster.com/nil/)

Answer (score 2):

With this line, you're assigning the zero value to a pointer, which is only a convention to define a null pointer, which doesn't address to any memory.

Here ([Why is address zero used for the null pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759845/why-is-address-zero-used-for-null-pointer)) you have a discussion about why zero is the null pointer convention in c.

Answer (score 1):

In C and, by extension, Objective-C, `0` is the equivalent of `NULL` and `nil` and `Nil`. It's an integer but it freely assigns to any pointer type.