# How do you express and use 'nothing' in C++?

Tags: c++, null

**Goal**

I want to know if there is a 'null' in C++, just like how there is `None` in Python or a `nil` in Ruby. I also want to know how you should use it.

**Code**

Here is my C++ code I made.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  bool value = _____;      // Are you supposed to use 'null' with a 'bool' type?
  std::cout << value;
}
```

**Attemps**

I tried replacing `_____` with `null`, `nil`, `Null`, and `Nil`, but none of them worked! I even tried to replace `_____` with `none` and `None`, but all I got was this error message (not complete error message):

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:16: error: 'None' was not declared in this scope
```

The website Repl.it even suggested to change `None` into `clone`. Should I?

```
main.cpp:5:16: note: suggested alternative: 'clone'
```

So how do you have 'null' fit into a variable, but is there even a 'null' in C++?

Comment: There is no such thing for non-pointers. In this case, a `bool` can be `true` or `false`, *that's it*.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? This seems like an X, Y problem as it stands.

Comment: Booleans can have only two possible values: true (1), and false (0).

Comment: A `bool` has just two possible values, represented by integers 0 and 1. You can define your own types that in addition can be "null". It's seldom a good idea. Or, OK, you can use `std::optional`. It's probably not a good idea for you to latch on to, but it's a technical possibility.

Comment: [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something like a `bool`, you have exactly two possible values, `true`, or `false`. There is no third "lack of value."

The way Python (I can't speak for Ruby) does this "lack of value" is by not actually storing `true` or `false` under the surface, but rather storing the address of a location storing true or false. When you ask what the value is, it goes to that address and checks.

This way, if you want "lack of value," it simply changes the address it's storing to the [null address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759845/why-is-address-zero-used-for-the-null-pointer). This allows for a pseudo "third possible value."

You can accomplish this in C++ by using a boolean pointer (ie: `bool *b`), but it's probably not a good idea. Depending on your situation there's almost definitely a better way to handle a "lack of value."

Alternatively, you could make an [`enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) with three possible values ie:

```
enum valState { ISGOOD, ISBAD, ISNULL };
```

Which will allow you to do:

```
valState state = ISBAD;
if(state == ISNULL) { ...
```

Comment: I do not know how you resisted `{ISGOOD, ISBAD, ISUGLY}` I couldn't have.

Answer (score 2):

The only time you can use `NULL` or `nullptr` is with a *pointer* type. Most simple types and classes don't have any none-style value equivalent.

In C++17 you can use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to wrap another type, but that's a distinct type and can't be used interchangeably with the base type.