# C Array address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, embedded

I want to make 64 4-Byte long array and I want the start address to be what I want, say `0x1000_0000`.

```
int wspace[64];  //this makes a 64 int array
```

I want `wspace` to be located at a particular location of my choice.
How Can I do that?

Comment: Please specify your environment and why you have a need to be in control of the address of your allocated RAM

Comment: The linker should have an input file that partitions memory and maps variables to specific partitions, or even addresses within a partition. That file is not standardized, so the answer to your question depends on which tool chain you're using, and which OS/processor you're targeting.

Answer (score 4):

You're starting to get into a grey area of possibly undefined behaviour but, if you *know* what you're doing (such as if you're on an embedded system and you have memory-mapped I/O or other valid writable stuff at that location), then you can just try:

```
int *wspace = (int *)0x10000000;
```

Depending on your compiler and environment, you may want to mark it as volatile as well, so that the implementation understands the memory may change independently of anything done to it by said compiler:

```
volatile int *wspace = (volatile int *)0x10000000;
```

It's not *technically* an array but, unless you're going to do something like `sizeof` on it, that probably won't really matter.

Once you've done that, then a statement like `wspace[1] = 0x12345678` should write that value to memory locations `0x10000004-0x10000007` (for a 4-byte `int`). Just keep in mind that *which* part of the number goes into which memory location will depend on the endian-ness of your architecture.

Comment: You also need `volatile`, if this is indeed a memory mapped IO region. This, along with some other useful techniques, is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389251/pointer-to-a-specific-fixed-address

Comment: Whether you _need_ volatile depends on a lot of things, including the standard you're working against, but you're right that it's a good idea. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a section in the linker file which start at this address and put this variable only in this section, the possibility of doing this will depend on your architecture.