# How to get a value from a memory adress in C?

Tags: c, memory-management

A bit of a silly question but here it is - how do I get a value based on its address?

Usually to get the address for a certain value I just print it out like this:

```
printf("%p", &loc);
```

But now I need to get a value based on its address in memory. How do I do that?

Comment: That would depend on what is the effective type of `loc`. C *is* a statically typed language...

Comment: loc can be put as #define loc 0x100

Comment: If you have the address of a value, then you have a pointer. You should use the dereference operator to dereference the pointer an you get the value. The type of the pointer must match the data type you want to read.

Comment: Then your entire code is ill-formed. You can't take the address of a constant

Comment: Where did you get `loc` from? You might be looking to set a volatile pointer to it, but that’s a bit rare. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389251/pointer-to-a-specific-fixed-address if that’s really the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of accessing a particular address 0x12345678 (such as a hardware register) is:

```
(volatile uint32_t*)0x12345678
```

If you want to use the contents of that address as if it was a variable, you could either have a pointer point there, or make a macro:

```
#define REGISTER ( *(volatile uint32_t*)0x12345678 )
```

Answer (score 3):

The addressof operator returns an object that is a pointer type. The value of the pointer is the memory address of the pointed object (which is `loc`). You can get the value of the object at the pointed memory address by dereferencing the pointer with the dereference operator:

```
*(&loc)
```

Answer (score 1):

An address has no type, but assuming you know it, you may use the follow line:

```
printf("%d", *(int*)p);
```

You could test several types to check what is in there:

```
printf("%d", *(int*)p);
printf("%f", *(float*)p);
...
```

Be careful, that the address is required to belong to the current process, if not, the memory protection will kill your process.

Comment: Did you mean `*(int*)p` and `*(float*)p`?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use the asterisk to get the value of the variable the pointer is pointing to.

```
type x = *loc
```

i used type because i don't know the type of loc(it may be int, double, float,...)