# Why can I not assign a memory address number to a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

We know a pointer has a name and a value, the essence is variable, the value is hexadecimal number which is a memory address.

```
int a = 10;
int * p = &a;

cout << p << endl;  // 0x7ffee04fe2b8

int * q = 0x7ffee04fe2b8;  // why can not assign address number to the pointer `q`?
```

[image]

---

If I assign `0x0`, it works:

```
int * q = 0x0;
```

The `0x0` refer to NULL, whether because of the interpreter take special handling.

I use CLion editor.

---

**EDIT**

I tried to declare as `long`, got issue too:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

I use 64-bit macOS.

The pointer value stores a memory address, so I want to try to assign the address directly.  Why can I not use this method?

```
int a = 10;
int * p = &a;

cout << p << endl;  // 0x7ffee04fe2b8

long q = 0x7ffee04fe2b8;
cout << * (int *)q << endl;  // prints nothing
```

---

**EDIT**

I tried this post: [Pointer to a specific fixed address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389251/):

```
int a = 10;
int * p = &a;

cout << p << endl;  // 0x7ffee04fe2b8

volatile unsigned int *myPointer = (volatile unsigned int *)0x7ffee04fe2b8;

cout << *myPointer << endl;  // print nothing
```

But why does it not print anything?

It builds successful, but when I run it, it prints nothing with `*myPointer`.

```
====================[ Build | untitled | Debug ]================================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/luowensheng/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug --target untitled -- -j 4
[100%] Built target untitled

Build finished
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218491/discussion-on-question-by-aircraft-why-can-not-assign-memory-address-number-to-c).

Comment: The value of a pointer is **not** a hexadecimal number. It's just **displayed** that way. Values aren't decimal, octal, hexadecimal, or whatever. When you convert them to text in order to look at them the text has a base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C language you **CAN** assign addresses from constants. It is not a good idea. But you can do it.

Example compiler error:

```
$ cat c-ptr-test.c
int main() {
  long *p = 0x0011223344556677;
  return 0;
}
$ make c-ptr-test
cc -Wall -W -pedantic -g -O3 -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -pthread -MMD  -std=c11   -pthread -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects  c-ptr-test.c   -o c-ptr-test
c-ptr-test.c: In function ‘main’:
c-ptr-test.c:2:13: warning: initialization of ‘long int *’ from ‘long int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    2 |   long *p = 0x0011223344556677;
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c-ptr-test.c:2:9: warning: unused variable ‘p’ [-Wunused-variable]
    2 |   long *p = 0x0011223344556677;
      |         ^
```

Two warnings but GCC compiled it successfully.

However, in the C++ language it requires an explicit cast. You're supposed to use `reinterpret_cast` but an old C style cast will also work.

Comment: There you go.  +1.  This is exactly what I mentioned in my comments.  Always actually compile your application, as the third-party tool's suggestions are ok, but are not fool-proof.

Comment: I tried GCC 10.1 9.1 but both shows as [errors](https://godbolt.org/z/svvczf). Is it related to compiler options?

Comment: @LouisGo Ah, C++. Different language. You're right, C++ won't compile that. Use `reinterpret_cast<long*>(0x0011223344556677)`

`reinterpret_cast` is also known as "break my program in ways impossible to debug`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to assign pointer while not telling compiler you "want" to assign it.

Your compiler error should looks like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/svvczf).

> invalid conversion from 'long int' to 'int*'

To assign the addres, the syntax should be `int *q = (int*)0x7ffee04fe2b8;`,while `(int*)` means "this value is an address of pointer `int*`.

Or a more modern way : `int * q = reinterpret_cast<int*>( 0x7ffebfc7019c );`

However you must to know what are you doing. Unless you're coding low level code with hardware registers, never hardcoded address.

Also everytime you execute the code, its address might not be the same as last time.

Try following code: or on GCC 10.1 https://godbolt.org/z/8zn7j5

```
int main()
{
   int a = 10;
    int * p = &a;

    cout << p << endl;

    long addr = (long)p;
    int * q = reinterpret_cast<int*>( addr );
    cout << *q << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your way will print nothing: `cout << *q << endl; `. try it.

Comment: @aircraft check my edit. You can't hardcode address. The address must be read from previous pointer.

Comment: Have you printed the `*q` as 10? why I use `reinterpret_cast<int*>` print nothing?

Comment: Hve you tried godbolt? I tested on that online compiler.

Comment: @aircraft Example is compiled and print 10 on gcc 10.1. Here's the link https://godbolt.org/z/8zn7j5 . You might need to check your compiler if it doesn't work.